# Should studies sampling from a single site be treated as cluster sampled?

Tags: sampling, sample-size

I'm fairly unfamiliar with sampling theory, but it seems to me that a study sampling from a single location (e.g. a university) is a single-cluster sample, as long as the study aims to generalize to a larger population. Is that the case, or should we treat the single-site sample as simple and random?

If they count as cluster samples, should single-site studies' standard errors be adjusted by an estimated design effect?